# Как правильно составить схему таблицы для объекта, взаимодействующего со многими другими?

Tags: sql, база-данных

К примеру для объекта, который логирует операции(изменение, удаление, создание и т.д.), происходящие в других объектах.

Текущая схема следующая:

- id
- operation_id
- related_class
- related_record_id

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что именно вы собираетесь логировать. По вашему текущему описанию, вам более чем достаточно того, что есть.

Comment: Большинство действий пользователя в программе.
К примеру - подтверждение, создание, удаление документов(хранящихся в разных таблиц) и т. д..

Comment: Это, по-вашему, подробнее? Впрочем, если это действительно **вся** необходимая информация, тогда в чем ваши затруднения?

Comment: На самом деле, почти вся :)

"в чем ваши затруднения?"

Невозможность добавления внешнего ключа (для поля related_record_id).
Это самому тогда проверять?

Comment: В смысле - невозможность добавления ключа? Покажите тогда ваш DDL скрипт и какую ошибку выдает СУБД.

Comment: А как добавить FK для related_record_id, если он меняется в зависимости от значения поля related_class? Это возможно?

Comment: Так вы хотите, чтобы это поле ссылалось на несколько разных таблиц? Так нельзя, насколько я знаю. Если ваши объекты, на которые вы хотите ссылаться, слишком разные для того, чтобы объединять их в одну таблицу, то могу предложить только триггером проверять.

Comment: "Так вы хотите, чтобы это поле ссылалось на несколько разных таблиц?"
- Да, объединить не получится, сущности слишком разные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помимо указанных вами полей неплохо бы добавить следующие (в зависимости от полноты логирования, естественно):

- user
- opertaion_datetime
- old_value
- new_value

Comment: Пользователя и дату добавил. А в old_value, new_value что хранить?

Comment: Иногда бывает нужным узнать, что на что изменили (при update, к примеру). Забыл добавить поле "change_column" - какой столбец изменили. Проверки лучше делать на триггерах к соответствующим таблицам (или в хранимках, если операции с данными производятся не напрямую). Никакие foreign key тут не нужны (К примеру, вы удалил апись - зачем вам ссылка?).

Comment: Триггеры - код, выполняемые по происшествии определенных событий. В них осуществляют проверку данных, прав, логирование. Это как раз ваш случай - ознакомьтесь, если еще этого не сделали. Иногда процесс добавления, изменения, удаления происходит через хранимые процедуры - в этом случае все проверки и логирование можно произвести там. Скорее всего, вам это не нужно и достаточно будет одного-двух триггеров на каждую таблицу вашей схемы, которые хотите логировать.

Comment: А не лучше вынести информацию об изменённых данных (old_value, new_value) в отдельную таблицу?
Ведь можно сразу несколько полей изменить в связанной таблице.

Comment: Если изменится несколько полей - просто вставите несколько строк в триггере. Триггер, который срабатывает, к примеру, на обновление данных, "знает", что изменилось несколько полей - если вы изменили название книги и автора, синтаксис будет примерно таким (oracle): `CREATE TRIGGER tr_book_table
   BEFORE UPDATE OF book_table
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   IF (:new.book_name != :old.book_name)
     -- логирование
   END ID;
   IF (:new.author != :old.author)
     -- логирование
   END ID;
   END;`
А писать в отдельную таблицу или в ту же - зависит от вашей БД.

Comment: По комментам выше (не могу писать в ту ветку) - **зачем** вам, таки, именно FK? Он там не то что не нужен, он просто вреден.

Comment: Мне нужна возможность, которую предоставляет FK - добавить её в свою таблицу не могу, поэтому да - нужен триггер.

Comment: А вообще - нормальная ли это практика? Не лучше ли для каждой сущности создать отдельную таблицу для логирования?

Comment: Все зависит от объемов, как по мне. Если у вас миллион записей на все таблицы и изменение данных сравнительно не часто - можно и в одну. Если данных много и меняются часто - можно и в разные. Как удобнее именно вам, за такое никто не осудит. Опять же, можно разделить не по таблицам - к примеру, ошибки - в одну таблицу, изменение данных в другую, прикрепленные файлы - в третью и т. д.